# Prove that $X$ is a compact .

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be a subset of $R^n$ and every differentiable function on $X$ is bounded, then prove that $X$ is compact.

Comment: A modification of this should work : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577878/construction-of-a-continuous-function-which-is-not-bounded-on-given-interval

Answer (score 4):

By considering the smooth function $f(x) = \|x\|^2$, we see that $X$ must be bounded.

Now suppose $y \notin X$, and define $g_y(x) = \frac{1}{\|x-y\|^2}$. Then $g_y$ is smooth on $X \subset \{y\}^c$. Since $g_y$ is bounded, we must have some neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that $U \cap X = \emptyset$, hence $X^c$ is open.

Now apply Heine–Borel.